# Eclipse cannot find android:id="@+id/android: names

Tags: android, eclipse

Please why do I have such a situation?

I have defined 2 ListViews in my XML, and I named them

```
android:id="@+id/android:listbest"
```

and

```
android:id="@+id/android:listworst"
```

When I try to reference them from my code Eclipse apparently is not able to find those ids.

I reference them as follows:

```
v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listaworstbest, container, false);    
lvBest= (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.listbest);
lvWorst=(ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.listworst);
```

I have cleaned and rebuilt the project several times but without success.

[image]

My XML should be fine, I see no errors.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#1414FF">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titolo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:text="Best and Worst stocks"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#00EBEB"
         />  
         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/best"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:text="Best stocks"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titolo"
        android:textColor="#00EBEB"
         />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dip" 
    android:background="#1414FF">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:text="Nome"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#00EBEB"
         />


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:ems="8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:text="Simbolo" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nome"
        android:textColor="#00EBEB"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prezzo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:text="Ultimo prezzo" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="#00EBEB"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"    
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cambiamento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Variazione"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#00EBEB"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:listbest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#1414FF">

        <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:text="Worst stocks"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:textColor="#00EBEB"
         />

      </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:listworst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="#1414FF" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dettagliobtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Details" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favoritesbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Favorites" />

      </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:
WHY IS IT WORKING IN THIS CASE?????**

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         >
    </ListView>
```

The Java is:

```
View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista, container, false);    
        lv= (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Thanks!!!
Cheers!
pietmau

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change Both ListViews id's to

`First ListView` id to :

```
 android:id="@+id/listworst"
```

and

`Second ListView` Id to

```
android:id="@+id/listbest"
```

and refere them as:

```
v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listaworstbest, container, false);    
lvBest= (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listbest);
lvWorst=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listworst);
```

Comment: Thank you, but please why?? ListViews aren't supposed to be named android:id="@+id/android:listbest" so that can be used in the code (i.e. add Adapter and so on...)?? Thanks

Comment: the problem is with `android:` as part of the id declaration.  You were so close!

Comment: @pietmau The proper notation is `"@android:id/list"`. But you cannot create your own ids in the android R file (`"@android:id/listbest"` is not allowed), you can create new ids in your own.

Comment: @pietmau : because both id's listbest and listworst not exists in android.R file